# what is the smallest possible value of $|G|?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group that has element of every order from 1 through 12

what is the smallest possible value of $|G|$

---

Found thm

If $G$ is finite group

1. $a\in G \Rightarrow |a|\mid|G| $
2. $|G|=k \Rightarrow a^k=e\ \forall a\in G$

---

I think its 12

Comment: It can't be twelve. Not that $5$ does not divide $12$, so a group of order $12$ cannot have an element of order $5$.

Comment: its the least common multiple ? of 12,11,,10,9, ... 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finite group with elements of every order $1, 2, \dots ,12$, and let $n$ be the order of the group. By Lagrange's Theorem, $n$ must be a multiple of all of those numbers. Thus $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots,12) \mid n$. Therefore $n$ cannot be less than $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots,12)$.

Conversely, when a group is cyclic of order $n$, it has elements of every order dividing $n$. Thus the smallest possible order is $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots,12) = 27720.$

Answer (score 1):

Because of your first point, we know that $|G|$ must be at least

$$\underbrace{2\times3\times5\times7\times11}_{\text{primes}}\times\underbrace{4\times3}_{\text{for $4,8,9$ and $12$}}$$

Can you think of a group $G$ with this order that satisfies your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Since the order of an element needs to divide the order of a group, the order of $G$ has to be at least $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,...,12)$ which is $27720$. Bun notice that for every divisor of a cyclic group there exists an element of that order. Thus, an example of such group would be $\mathbb{Z}_{27720}$. Thus, the smallest such group has $27720$ elements.